# facebook loginbutton sdk in c# crashing application

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-3.0

I need a small help
I have created a small physioit app for windows phone 8.

I have added facebookclient loginbutton in my xaml file.
Now when there is no data connection in my phone and when I run the code, it gives me `TargetInvocationException` and my app crashes.

Here is the exception I am getting –

```
innerException 
{Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. --->
      System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
 at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
 at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---}           

System.Exception     {Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper}
```

How can I catch this exception?

I am using the facebook sdk to create the loginbutton

Here is the code snippet

```
<facebookControls:LoginButton
    x:Name="loginButton"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    FetchUserInfo="True"      
    ApplicationId="xxxxxx" 
    SessionStateChanged="OnFacebookSessionStateChanged"
    UserInfoChanged="OnFacebookUserInfoChanged"
    AuthenticationError="LoginButtonAuthenticationError" />
```

Can you please help me out.

Comment: Nice catch, that is weird. I suppose it shouldn't be crashing the app by design. Have you reported the issue at the https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues? 

Two possible workarounds are 
1) not using the login button for login 

2) not attaching the ApplicationId until you're sure that there's Internet connectivity (tricky)

Comment: Just a guess - make sure you've enabled all the capabilities facebook sdk requires in your wmappmanifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You could use NetworkInterface to check whether data connection is available or not and then allow the login button to do its action.

Something like this..

```
if(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
//Allow login button
else
//Message user - no internet connection
```